# Dr.Racket for SICP

Tags: ssl, scheme, sicp

I am setting up DR.Racket for SICP. By following this guide 
http://docs.racket-lang.org/sicp-manual /index.html?q=sicp#%28part._.Introduction_to_the__lang_sicp_language%29

But I am not able to download sicp package. Following is the error message I recieved after hitting install.

Resolving "sicp" via https://download.racket-lang.org/releases/6.11/catalog/
ssl-connect: connect failed (error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed)

Please explain what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Apologies if I'm telling you things you already know: it appears that certificate validation failed while contacting the racket package server.

There are several things that could cause this, but I have a sneaking suspicion that you have some kind of proxy standing between you and the server that is rewriting your traffic. Is this possible?

One way to test this would be to try installing the package on a different computer, connected to a different network.

(FWIW, I just tested this installation myself, and didn't encounter this problem. So, at a minimum, it's not that the world is broken :).)